# Use mongodb $nin and $in operator with field value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is it possible to use the `$in` and `$nin` Operator in an aggregation with the value from a field or a variable from a pipeline? I have an Array of objectId's as pipeline variable and would like to get all documents except these ids. Is there a workaround or another approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$addFields` to project a helper field for filtering. Then, do a `$match` on the helper field.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "isValid": {
        "$in": [
          "$_id",
          [
            ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
            ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001")
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      isValid: false
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XKY5aE_KUTS) for your reference

Comment: Thanks this works. I only tried it with $match this is why it didn't work.